# Ошибка 500 при создании веб-приложения на Hibernate и Servlet

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, servlet

Добрый день.
Создали базу данных, создали для нее Hibernate зависимости и сущности. 
Проверили работу без использования сервлета, все работает.

[Вся информация по бд здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726964/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-hibernate-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-org-hibernate-tool-schema-spi/727045#727045)

Код сервлета :

```
@WebServlet("/pasis")
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
    // Входные данные
    static Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    static {
        String[] q = {"июнь2016"};
        map.put("age", q);
        String[] f = {"Dog", "Cat"};
        map.put("type", f);
    }
    // Входные данные

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
    throws ServletException, IOException {

        resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=windows-1251");

        /*System.out.println("Pipekka");*/
        String result = HibernateUtil1.getAnimalsFromDb(map);
        System.out.println(result);
        resp.getWriter().append(result);
    }
}
```

Maven зависимости :

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>




    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok-maven</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.18.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Код HibernateUtil:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

При запуске сервлета, выходит следующая ошибка.

Лог ошибки из консоли:

```
10-Oct-2017 18:23:11.336 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [service.MainServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
 org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use 
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1606)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1561)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1540)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1514)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1434)
    at supportMethods.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    at supportMethods.Methods.filtrateAnimalsFromDb(Methods.java:26)
    at service.MainServlet.doGet(MainServlet.java:40)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
```

Методы запуска работы Hibernate:

```
 public static String getAnimalsFromDb (Map<String, String[]> incomeRequest){

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    List<Animal> list = getAnimal(session,incomeRequest);
    String result = jsonPrint(list);

    transaction.commit();

    session.close();

    HibernateUtil.shutdown();

    return result ;
}
```

Повторюсь, что без сервлета, все запросы проходят и выполняются как нужно.
При запуске сервера выходит эта ошибка.

P.S. Изначально выходила такая же ошибка, но с другими causes. Решили добавлением всех библиотек подгруженных Maven, в папку lib.

Comment: в hibernateutil да и в сервлете создай пустой конструктор. У хибернейта помню прикол с конструктурами

Comment: К сожалению не помогло(

Comment: возможно не хватает какой-то библеотеки

Answer (score 0):

В ошибке прямо написано, что нужно сделать

```
return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```